# How to make scrollController attach to scrollbar after switching to a different navigation tab

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview, scrollcontroller

I am building a flutter mobile app. There is a BottomNavigationBar in this page and 2 tabs in it. like this
tab1:
[image]
tab2:
[image]

in tab1 there is a button

in tab2 there is a SingleChildScrollView(code is following)

I want to when I click the button, the app switch to tab2 and scroll the SingleChildScrollView to bottom.

tab1:

```
 BlockImgButton(key:UniqueKey(),Icons.chat_outlined, _unReadMessageNumber,
    onPress: (){
          print("chat_outlined clicked!");
          setState(() {
            //switch to tab2
            (_bottomNavigationKey.currentWidget as BottomNavigationBar).onTap!(1);
           //controll slide
            _scrollController.animateTo(_scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent, duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500), curve: Curves.ease);

      });

}),
```

tab2:

```
Scrollbar(
    controller: _scrollController,
    thumbVisibility: true,
    child:SingleChildScrollView(
      controller: _scrollController,
      child:
      NavigationRail(
        //some contents in here
      )
    )
)
```

Now when I click the button in tab1, it can successfully switch to tab2 but can not make the Scrollbar to slide.

The Debug information output:

```
"SingleChildScrollView" ScrollController not attached to any scroll views.
```

I guess it is because scrollController can not find and attach to SingleChildScrollView when the current screen is in tab1. but how to solve it.

BTW, I tried

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {})
```

but it doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved that problem.

I make the scrollController to scroll at onPageChanged of the PageView, it works well now.

Cause when the onPageChanged is called and the index is in tab2, the scrollController has been attached.